# Copy all visible text with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to build an fx rate converter and for this I tried to copy from this webpage (http://www.nbs.rs/export/sites/default/internet/english/scripts/kl_srednji.html) the exchange rates from the table.
I know that normally

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.nbs.rs/export/sites/default/internet/english/scripts/kl_srednji.html")
text = driver.page_source
```

will get all the visible text which is present in the page source code, but unfortunately the table is not in the source code, so I can't extract it.
I also tried to find the body of the page, select all, and copy, 
but unfortunately the table itself was not selected.
Any idea how to do it? Or this is kind of a scrape protection to avoid getting the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because there is an iframe being loaded (try spotting it in the source code). Its `src` points to

```
http://www.nbs.rs/kursnaListaModul/srednjiKurs.faces?lang=eng
```

So that's the URL you want.

Comment: thank you, this solved my issue, next time I will be more attentive

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get visible text rendered by html you can do by following way:

```
text = driver.find_element_by_tag("body").text
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_tag'`

Comment: it looks like this was changed to:
```text = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text```